# How do I detect more than single tap?

Tags: java, android

I would like to detect single taps several times. I have an activity where the user can tap on an image, they should receive the Toast message, and the program should change the image to another one, and whenever the user taps on this image, there's should be another Toast message. To be more specific, I'll try to provide an example:
Let's say we have two images:
1 - straight line
2 - circle

when the user will enter the specified activity, should see one of those images in the toolbar (let's say that first of them are straight line). When the user will click on this image, the app should display Toast, and then change the straight line to a circle.

*By changing images I mean setting method like

```
circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // circle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Unfortunately, my switch case doesn't work as I intended. Whenever a user clicks on the first image, it's changing the visibility of those two, but look's like the OnClick method doesn't recognize another tap. Here's the code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.line: {
            Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            test = 2;
            break;
        }
        case R.id.circle: {
            Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
    switchImages();
}





private void switchImages(){
    switch (test){
        case 1:
            line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 2:{
            line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: please show what you are doing in `switchImages()` method

Comment: I'm just changing there the visibility of those images, as I meantioned above onClick method

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked please share code for this method how you are changing image visibility.

Comment: Are you sure that, line and circle have correct ids?

Comment: The method is in question for now. Yest, I'm sure about that.

Comment: So, your onClick method is called but later, code doesn't choose any option from the switch case? Also,  `switch (test)` what is test?

Answer (score 0):

You missed something.. ;)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.line: {
        Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        test = 2;
        break;
    }
    case R.id.circle: {
        Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
switchImages();
}
```

In the first case you are assigning `test = 2` but in the second one you don't do anything with that variable, so method `switchImages()` won't really do anything, since it depends on `test` which is 2 all the time (images will not switch accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing test in first case as `test = 2` but forget to initialize it in second case 
So just change the code :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.line: {
             Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             test = 2;
            break;
         }
         case R.id.circle: {
             Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             test = 1;
             break;
         }
       }
      switchImages();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have changed only `onClick(View v)` and removed `switchImages();`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.line: {
             Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "line", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
         }
         case R.id.circle: {
             Toast.makeText(TAG.this, "circle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             circle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             break;
         }
       }

   }
```

As per your question, if you click **line**, it will **toast** and make **visible circle** and hide **line** and *vice-versa*